# tikzexternal, asymptote and duplicated asy files

Tags: pdftex, tikz-external, asymptote, shell-escape

I'm trying to work with tikzexternal and asymptote for my documents.
Here is a sample TeX document :

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,angles}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw
  (3,-1) coordinate (a) node[right] {a}
  -- (0,0) coordinate (b) node[left] {b}
  -- (2,2) coordinate (c) node[above right] {c}
  pic["$\alpha$", draw=orange, <->, angle eccentricity=1.2, angle radius=1cm]
  {angle=a--b--c};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{asy}
  size(5cm,0);
  pair A=(0,0), B=(4,0);
  draw(A--B);
  dot("$A$",A,W);
  dot("$B$",B,E);
  dot("$I$",(A+B)/2,N);
\end{asy}
\end{document}
```

When I use `pdflatex --shell-escape test.tex`, I get a file named `test-1.asy`, which is my asy file, a file `test-figure0.pdf`, which is my tikz picture, and another `test-figure0-1.asy`, which is a copy of the original asy file.

Without using `--shell-escape`, I don't have the extra asy file.

Does anyone has any idea how to get rid of the creation of this last file ? Here it is not really a problem, but if I have 10 tikz picture and 12 asy images, I get 10*12=120 asy files totally useless.

Thanks.

Comment: If you don't need interactive 3d figures, you might try the [`asypictureB`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/asypictureb?lang=en) package as an alternative interface to Asymptote. If you do this, make sure that shell-escape is on and--equally importantly--the latexmk rule for Asymptote is off.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it did not workout. I replaced `\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}` with `\usepackage{asypictureB}` and `\begin{asy}` with `\begin{asypicture}{name=asymptoteB}`. I still have a file named `test-figure0-asymptoteB.asy` which is compiled in eps and the "real file" `test-asymptoteB.asy` which is copiled in eps and pdf format.

Comment: This is a shot in the dark, but have you tried putting your `asy` or `asypicture` environment inside the text of a tikz `node`? (Make sure the `\begin{asy}` and `\end{asy}` commands are on lines by themselves.) And this probably goes without saying, but make sure to delete all `*.asy` files before recompiling when you test something like this.

Comment: Thanks again for this try. It didn't work either. Still the two asy files at the end.